# Warning on deploying Flask app using AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codecommit, ebcli

```
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 100.0 % of the 
requests are erroring with HTTP 4xx. Insufficient request rate (6.0 
requests/min) to determine application health. ELB processes are not healthy 
on all instances. Configuration update in progress (running for 13 seconds). 
ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
```

Due to this warning I am getting an Internal Server Error. Can someone help me in understand the cause of this warning and how to work around it? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have all EC2 instances associated with EB up and running? Based on message it seems they are not (or) you have health check configurations wrong.

Comment: I have just one instance associated with it.. and it is running. Can you tell me specifically what do you mean by health check configurations going wrong.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html check "Single instance" section. Hope it helps.